# How to combine PrimeFaces InputGroup with an overlay SelectOneButton

Tags: css, primefaces

I want to build a component, based on InputGroup, with a button that should open a selection. Something more o less like this (please, ignore black border):

[image: desired behaviour]

When InputGroup p:button A (label '=') is clicked, it opens a p:selectOneButton B, so I can change A value based on B selection.

I have a basic functional script, it can be enhanced, but the simple behavior is accomplished, please fill free to make any improvements/suggestions:

```js
function changeSelectedFilter(evtTarget, tgtButton) {
  const op = evtTarget.getJQ().find(':checked').val();
  const A = PrimeFaces.getWidgetById(tgtButton);
  A.value = op;
  A.getJQ().children().text(op);
}
```

My major issue is with components usage and placement. I'm working with a p:tooltip for now, but it's not what I want, do you have any clues in how to hide/show B correctly placed above A and centered, so it looks like it is been expanded?

With accessibility concerns, this could not be a good approach, and p:menuButton/p:splitButton would be much better, but I want a simple button with just an icon (not default chevron down) and no text...

Here a comparison with p:splitButton and p:menuButton, with desired max-width:

[image]

Context: this is a numeric filter component added to columns in p:dataTable, this component current implementation uses a separated p:input and p:selectOneButton, but in 2 lines, so an overlay could optimize space.

Any suggestion with others components will be welcomed too!

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think that is the best UX. I would go for a [`p:splitButton`](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/button/splitButton.xhtml) instead. See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment

Comment: Agreed, @JasperdeVries. A p:splitButton or p:menuButton works pretty similar, and have all accessibility concerns included, but they are too big for my use case.

Comment: When you say "too big" do you mean the size of the button in the UI?  If so why not just tweak it with CSS?

Comment: Added more infos and additional image to question